# React createRef returning current = null when creating dynamic generated components

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

I have a React component which receives an object with the properties for generate some children components dynamically. While generating those new components I need to create a ref for each one of them, but `React.createRef()` is returning `current` as `null`.

Here is what I have done:

```
const source = {
   component1: {
      name: 'Component 1',
      active: true
   },
   component2: {
      name: 'Component 2',
      active: true
   },
   component3: {
      name: 'Component 3',
      active: false
   }
}
```

then this is the main component:

```
function MyComp(props) {
   const {source} = props;

   const refs = {};

   function makeComps() {
      const newComps = [];
      Object.keys(source).forEach(x => {
         const myRef = React.createRef();
         refs[x] = myRef;
         newComps.push(
         <div ref={myRef}>
           <div>Name</div>
           <div>{source[x].name}</div>

           <div>Active</div>
           <div>{source[x].active ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</div>
         </div>);
      });
      return newComps;
   }

   return (
      <>
        <strong>{'Brand new components'}</strong>
        {source && makeComps()}
        {!source && <div>Nothing new</div>}
      </>
   );
}
```

Then, when I try to get access to `refs` it returns:

```
{
   component1: {current: null},
   component2: {current: null},
   component3: {current: null}
}
```

I need these references to make a `window.scrollTo` on some condition. According to the React official documentation I am not doing nothing weird. Also I tried with `React.useRef()` instead, but nothing.

Here is how I am reaching this refs:

```
const myRef = refs.component3;
window.scrollTo({ behavior: 'smooth', top: myRef.current.offsetTop });
```

How can I solve this? What am I missing here?

Comment: In which way you try to access `refs`? **Edit:** Your code is working for me, all `refs` contain their current elements. I cannot reproduce your problem

Comment: It doesn't run for me. It is driving me out of my mind.

Comment: You need to be sure, that you access the `refs` after the first render. This is simply, because React doesn't resolves refs during the first render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you try to access them before the first render was done. In this case your component *did not mount*. Be sure it is, using the `useEffect` hook. [Learn more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

```
function MyComp({ source, ...props }) {
  const refs = {};

  function makeComps() {
    const newComps = [];

    Object.keys(source).forEach((x, idx) => {
      const myRef = React.createRef();
      refs[x] = myRef;

      newComps.push(
        <div key={idx} ref={myRef}>
          <div>Name</div>
          <div>{source[x].name}</div>
          <div>Active</div>
          <div>{source[x].active ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return newComps;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // here, your component did mount

    // try to access component1 using the optional
    // chaining feature of JavaScript
    console.log(refs.component1?.current);
  }, [refs]);

  return (
    <>
      <strong>{'Brand new components'}</strong>
      {source && makeComps()}
      {!source && <div>Nothing new</div>}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, [Kluddizz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10935599/kluddizz) here partially gave me the solution, although his solution does not provide the correct answer to my issue, he pointed me to the right solution. Hooks to the rescue:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (refs.component3 && refs.component3.current) {
      //do the magic
   }
});
```

His comment:

> You need to be sure, that you access the refs after the first render.
>   This is simply, because React doesn't resolves refs during the first
>   render.

was the entry point to the right solution.